# Applying own methods to h2

Tags: java, spring, jpa, h2

I have started to learn Spring and I am trying to store the title, genre, year and actor data for movies in a database (h2). How can I apply my own methods from my code to obtain the data from that database for printing it in console with a `system.out.println()`?

I have the classes for `Movie` and `Actor` with their correspondent attributes, both marked with `@Entity` annotation. Next, I have an interface that extends `JpaRepository` (I know that there is a default method to find all movies, but I want to create this functionality with an own method):

```java
public interface MovieDaoI extends JpaRepository<Movie, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT m FROM Movie m")
    public List<Movie> list();

}
```

Also, I have a H2 database initilized with 3 movies (using the properties file in the startup moment), and I can access to the h2 console and create SQL queries using the web interface. But what I want is to call my method `list()` in other class called `MoviesApplication` with a main method, and take the List that returns and print it in console with a simple `system.out.println()`. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: show the code and tell which part is not working

Comment: Assuming you use Spring Boot, create a command line runner (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner), injected the DAO on this cammand line runner, and use it.

Answer (score 0):

in your case,you are using JPQL instead of SQL query,
if you just want to use SQL query,then you should write like this below:
@Query(value = "SELECT m FROM Movie m ", nativeQuery = true)

Comment: What I mean is how can I call from other class this method and save this List<Movie> data so I can print it in console? Without using h2 console, because if I have this method implemented I should be able to call it from other class obtaining the data from the database, but I do not know how.

Comment: you have to creat  a new java class ,and write like below comment,and in this  java class to call interface java class

Answer (score 0):

@Service //you need add this @Service
public class Bookservice {

@Autowired  //you need add this @Autowired 
  private MovieDaoI movieDaoI ;

public List list() {
    return MovieDaoI .list();
  }

}

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear to my whats is your exact problem. but I think you've got issues with how to call repository methods in your bean.

In beans and also `SpringBootApplication` classes you can use `autowired` to get the created proxy of repository and just call the method:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class MoviesApplication {

    @AutoWired
    MovieDaoI movieDaoI;

    public void someMethod() {
        movieDaoI.list();
    }
}
```

But I don't think that is a good idea. Try to create a Service or create a test method